# Large braces to specify condition in a set

Tags: math-mode, braces

How do I define this in LaTeX - I am writing a description of a set, and I need huge braces because I have lot of clauses to fit in, and it will take more than 1 line. For example:

`A = \{ (x,y,z) : \exists ... \forall ... (big definition of a graph)\}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the [amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package, the proper solution would be to break the long definition using `multline` (or `multline*` for no equation number):

```
\begin{multline}
A = \{ (x, y, z) \colon \exists \dots \forall \dots \\
    \text{(your big definition of a graph goes here)} \}
\end{multline}
```

If you insist on having large braces around the definition of your set you can use something like:

```
\begin{equation}
A = \left\{ 
  \begin{aligned}
  &(x, y, z) \colon \exists \dots \forall \dots \\ 
  &\text{(your big definition of a graph goes here)}
  \end{aligned}
\right\}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your preamble:

```
\usepackage{braket} % needed for \Set
```

In your math mode:

```
A = \Set{ (x,y,z) : \exists ... \forall ... (big definition of a graph)}
```

Comment: This is a great answer since it makes the '(x,y,z)' centered in the vertical direction. In addition one may add arrays of conditions in place of the 'big definition'.

Answer (score 2):

For one line, you can use

```
\left\{ (x,y,z) : bla bla \right\}
```

For multiple lines, for example

```
\begin{align*}
      & \left\{ (x,y,z) : bla bla \right. \\
      & \hspace{1cm} \left. bla bla bla \right\}
\end{align*}
```